# Hide button if it shows only once, show button if it shows more than once

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to hide the remove button if it shows only once, i.e. if there is 1 form hide the remove button, if I clone the form then show the remove button.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/d8Tj8/30/

Here's the html

```
<button class="clone">Clone</button> 
<div id="upload_image_sets">
  <div id="clonedInput1" class="clonedInput">
    <input type="text" id="upload_image_link_1" class="image" size="36" name="hero_options[upload_image_link_1]" value="' . $hero_options['upload_image_link_1'] . '" />
    <input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
    <div class="actions">
      <button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple, hide the button with CSS, show it when cloning and remove it when clicked and only one remains:

**CSS**

```
.remove { display: none; }
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var cloneIndex = $(".clonedInput").length + 1;
    var new_Input = $(".clonedInput").first().clone();
    updateClonedInput(cloneIndex, new_Input);
    $('.remove').show(); // show the button on cloning
});
$(document).on("click", "button.remove", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents(".clonedInput").remove();
    $(".clonedInput").each( function (cloneIndex, clonedElement) {
        updateClonedInput(cloneIndex + 1, clonedElement);
    });
    if ($('.remove').length == 1) $('.remove').hide(); //remove it if it is the last one when removing
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/slash197/d8Tj8/45/

Comment: Perfect. I knew it would be simple but I couldn't get my head round it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After you clone form and on clicking remove button call function:

```
function showRemoveButton(){
    if ($('.clonedInput').length > 1) //how much forms currently presented.
        $('.remove').show();
    else
        $('.remove').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just hidden `remove` button at first:

```
<button class="remove" style="display: none">Remove</button>
```

then in `clone` button, show it for new elements:

```
$(document).on("click", "button.clone", function(e){
    .
    .
    .    

    $(new_Input).find("button.remove").show();
});
```

check this: http://jsfiddle.net/hSWM9/

Comment: according to @slash197 and @Muthukannan posts, there is no need to `remove` button for first input at all, check attached fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated jsfiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/d8Tj8/50/

`function displayRemove() {
    if($('.clonedInput').length === 1) {
        $('.actions').hide();
    } else {
        $('.actions').show();
    }
}`

Even if you had more than one form intially, this approach would work.